# Applying knowledge that was learned through breaking Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, employment

If one studies a topic on Shabbat through doing melacha, is he allowed to benefit from the knowledge he gains? For example, if one studied and practiced fixing cars on Shabbat and then did teshuvah for this, could he later become a mechanic using these skills?

Does it make a difference if the knowledge and skills gained on Shabbat were:

1. For the purpose of applying them to a job later
2. For entertainment on Shabbat
3. A combination of (2) and (3)

Comment: Hi @Yos and welcome to Mi Yodeya it is great to have you learn with us! Could I trouble you to make the question a bit clearer because at the moment it is not so easy to understand.

Comment: It seems like the knowledge gained was done in an indirect manner.  The main issue is doing melalcha and gaining from that actual Malachi. So the question would apply to the car worked on itself ,but the knowledge gained is indirect

Comment: @sam The original question mentioned reading books on a computer. The example here too with the car is not talking about a situation where the car had a practical need for fixing -- it was fixed just for the sake of learning. Maybe these situations are more direct. What do you think?